# Lync: ConversationAdded not fired for Response groups

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

I have a weird Problem with one of my Clients Lync system.

For his Clients the `conversationAdded` Event is not fired for a Repsonse Group call, but for a direct call.

The Response Group Settings are set to `formal` and the Routing method to `Attended`.

I have the same Setup in my local lync Network and here the Event is fired regardless of reaction group or not.

Thanks

**Edit/Update 11/27/2013**
yesterday and today I tested it on 5 Clients in the same network.
My results are:
4 Windows 7/8 Clients with Lync 2010/2013: not working
1 Server 2012 / Lync 2013: working.

I really have no idea whats wrong with this system.